# Wordpress и PHP переменые

Tags: php, wordpress, css

Вопрос: как можно использовать объявленные глобальными переменные, которые были изменены в цикле. Для чего мне это надо? Объясню: необходимо изменять фон части страницы, смотря от того, какая фотография загружена в запись. Итак, код 
functions.php 
    global $theBackOneStep;
indexpages.php (не весь футер хедер подключен).

```
<?php $myposts = get_posts("include=8");
                    foreach ($myposts  as $post) :
                    setup_postdata($post);
                ?>
                    <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt();?> </p>
                    <?php $theBackOneStep=  catch_that_image();/*функция которая выводит адрес первого изображения подключено в function.php */ ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

header.php(среди прочих)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/styles.php" type="text/css">
```

styles.php

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");?>
   div.stepOne{
        background:url('<?php echo "$theBackOneStep;"?>') no-repeat;
    }
```

Вопрос в том, что background:url не работает в firebag, вообше пусто показывает, причем на странице indexpages.php адрес выводиться, когда пытаюсь вывести на других страницах, адрес не выводиться, в том числе и styles.php

В чем проблема, может, кто-нибудь что-нибудь подскажет? Причем уже отформатировал даже functions.php

Теперь она выглядит так:

```
  global $theBackOneStep;   
        $myposts = get_posts("include=8");
        foreach ($myposts  as $post) :
        setup_postdata($post);
        $theBackOneStep =  catch_that_image();  
        endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалась куда как проще: надо было подключить все функции wordpress, к style.php это сделать оказалось легко

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

в самом начале документа и все заработало.

Comment: и получили дополнительно полсекунды к загрузке css, которые там не нужны и наверняка не кэшируются

Comment: loder.js в помощь призову, там сайт весомый будет.

Answer (score 2):

**Причина**

Глобальные переменные не сохраняются между вызовами php. Загрузка страницы - один вызов, где определяется глобальная перем. А запрос к styles.php — уже другой вызов, с первым никак не связанный.

**Решение**

Вместо генерирования стилей в отдельном файле, просто добавьте в коде самой страницы после вывода постов в цикле блок `<style> ... </style>`, где и определите фон `div.stepOne`.

Comment: Да, я думал о том, что не подключается function.php, но использовать стили внутри веб-страницы, а не в отдельном css файле не рекомендуется w3c. Я честно пытался подключить function.php через include, но тоже не подключается. Можете что-либо посоветовать?

Comment: Первый совет в самом ответе : ) Посместить CSS в теле документа — меньшее зло, чем выполнить лишний HTTP запрос и запустить лишний PHP скрипт.

Может, вообще, inline-CSS дописать тому `<div>`'у?

    <div class="stepOne" style="background:url('<?php echo "$theBackOneStep;"?>') no-repeat;">...</div>

**Второй вариант** сделать эту стилизацию вообще на клиенте через JS. Т.е. переписать хитрую ф-ю `catch_that_image()` на JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Объявите `$theBackOneStep` как глобальную в файле стилей.